# Using graphs, how can I show that the logistic function is just an inverse logit function in R?

Tags: r, glm, bayesian, bernoulli-probability

To plot my logistic function, I used:

> plot(plogis, from = -10, to = 10)
>   My x values were: -10 to 10

So, based off of that graph's output, what should I do next?

Edit: If I plot the logistic function, y = logistic(x) = 1/(1+exp(−x)), how do I go about plotting the logit function, y = log(x/(1−x)), using the output from the logistic function's y values?

Comment: Hi, you should add a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), it will be easier to help you with that. I think you should also clarify a bit your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is too long for a comment.

```
x = seq(-10,10, 0.2)
y = 1/(1+exp(−x))
plot(x,y, type="l")
plot(y,x, type="l")
```